# Working with json data returned by web service

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, soap

I have created a Soap client to request data from web services and the returned data is displayed like this with my CodeIgniter function"

```
{"GetCodeResult":
{
"Selling":"1000.67114",
"Buying":"9000.65789"
}
}
```

but I want to format them like this by removing the getCodeResult

```
{"selling":"1000.67114","Buying":"9000.65789"}
```

Comment: Obvious question **WHY?**

Comment: Another question, what part of that are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this may help you.

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{"GetCodeResult":
                {
                    "Selling":"1000.67114",
                    "Buying":"9000.65789"
                }
            }';
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

$arr_index = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {    
    $arr_index = $value;    
}

echo json_encode($arr_index, true);
?>
```

Thanks.

If you want to get only the values of selling and buying means, try like below.

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{"GetCodeResult":
                {
                    "Selling":"1000.67114",
                    "Buying":"9000.65789"
                }
            }';
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

$arr_index = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    if($key == 'GetCodeResult'){
        $arr_index = $value;
    }    
}
foreach($arr_index as $values){
    $finalVal[] = $values;
}

echo json_encode($finalVal, true);
?>
```

Comment: It works Ramya thanks!

Comment: Ramya, i have a the result looks like this [{"SellingRate":"3.65500","BuyingRate":"3.64500"}]{"iso_name":"QAR"}

Comment: now iwant to display only the values example 3.65500, 3.64500 and QAR

Comment: can you please add the entire json in here.

Comment: the first line shows the function from api which is returning two values selling and buying

Comment: but i want to echo only values not with their variables

Comment: @DidosRukundo You know there are another answer here also

Answer (score 0):

Decode to array and return only the 'GetCodeResult' then json_encode it.

```
echo json_encode(json_decode($json, true)['GetCodeResult']);

//{"Selling":"1000.67114","Buying":"9000.65789"}
```

https://3v4l.org/59RSc

---

To only echo the values you can assign them to variables using list and array_values.

```
list($selling, $buying) = array_values(json_decode($json, true)['GetCodeResult']);

echo $selling .PHP_EOL;
echo $buying .PHP_EOL;
//1000.67114
//9000.65789
```

https://3v4l.org/T5GNg